# Are there 3rd party tools or good custom queries for WSUS 3.0?

Tags: wsus, patch-management

I'm working with a WSUS SP2 server, and I'm looking for ways to generate better reports.  The built-in reporting system, is almost (but not quite) useless.

My reading suggests that WSUS stores it's data in a SQL database, is anyone out there writing custom queries for WSUS or are there any 3rd party tools out there to help generate useful reports?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this will help, but Microsoft released something called the [WSUS Reporting Rollup Sample Tool](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/wsus/bb466192.aspx) that appears to demonstrate custom reporting in WSUS.

Comment: I saw that it could have something I could use, have you tried it at all?

Comment: I haven't - it just sounded like it might meet the criteria.